# Python insert vs Ruby insert

Tags: python, arrays, ruby

Python and Ruby all have the insert method.

Python:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a.insert(0, 0)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Ruby:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.insert(0,0)
# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

They have the same effect, but if give negative index, the result is different.

Python:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a.insert(-1, 6)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
```

Ruby:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.insert(-1, 6)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Why there is this differences? How to understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the python : insert(x, val), it means insert to the location before x.

```
so, a.insert(-1, 6)-> put the 6 before -1(location)
```

in the ruby : it means insert to this location x.

```
so, a.insert(-1, 6)-> put the 6 at -1.
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python, the new object is inserted before the element of that certain index. Given an insertion point of `0`, a new element is inserted before the item at index `0`, which results in the inserted item becoming first. Given an insertion point of `-1`, a new element is inserted before the last item, so it becomes the second-to-last element.

If you want to insert something to the end of a Python `list`, simply use `append()`.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, `insert()` with negative index is more consistent with positive index. `a.insert(i, x)` is always equivalent to `a[i:i] = [x]`. However, you can't use negative index to insert after the end.

You could use `a.insert(len(a), x)` which is equivalent to `a.append(x)`.

---

In Ruby, [`Array#insert`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-insert) explicitly says the new value is inserted **after** the element if the index is negative:

> Negative indices count backwards from the end of the array, where `-1` is the last element. If a negative index is used, the given values will be inserted after that element, so using an index of `-1` will insert the values at the end of the array.